# Comparing vectors

Tags: r

I would like to test the following: for each value in `x1` test if it falls between `x2` and `x3`. Basically if `x2$x2` < `x1` < `x2$x3` is true return the values of `x1` where it's true.  In this case they will all be true. I am confused if I should write a function or if there is something inbuilt to do this?

```
x1 <- data.frame(x1=11:20, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> x1
   x1
1  11
2  12
3  13
4  14
5  15
6  16
7  17
8  18
9  19
10 20

x2 <- 1:10
x3 <- 21:30
x2 <- data.frame(x2, x3, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> x2
   x2 x3
1   1 21
2   2 22
3   3 23
4   4 24
5   5 25
6   6 26
7   7 27
8   8 28
9   9 29
10 10 30
```

Comment: Does 
`x1[which(x2$x2 < x1  & x1 < x2$x3)]` 
give you what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

x1$x1[which(x1$x1 > x2$x2 & x1$x1 < x2$x3)]

`which` returns a vector of indices for which the equation (in this case, `x1$x1 > x2$x2 & x1$x1 < x2$x3` holds true. We then select the right elements using `x1$x1[indices]`.

Note the use of `&` instead of `&&` in the inequality, as you are working with vectors and not individual elements.

Comment: this will work without the `which` since logical tests already return a vector of logicals you can subset with them: `x1[x1$x1 > x2$x2 & x1$x1 < x2$x3,]`.  However, in your example all values fall within these parameters :)

Comment: Thank a bunch everyone this helps a lot. Its a pretty sad thing that I couldn't think of this myself.